# JQuery Fade Hidden Field In And Out On Select Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have this jquery code that is supposed to show and hide a field based on the content on what is selected:

```
$('#State').on('change', function() {
var s = $('#State option:selected').text;

if(s !== "")
{
    $('#showme').fadeIn();
}
if(s === "")
{
    $('#showme').fadeOut();
}

});
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b0h6xd0t/

It will fade the field in, but it won't fade it back out for some reason. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **jQuery**, `text()` is method. Methods, in order to work, **require the use of the parentheses** as shown below:

```
var s = $('#State option:selected').text(); // I added: ()
```

**Note**: In JavaScript, **the `empty string` is considered `false`**. So for neatness, you can turn your code into the following:

```
$('#State').on('change', function() {
    var s = $('#State option:selected').text();

    if(s) { // If it's true
        $('#showme').fadeIn();
    }
    else { // If it's false
        $('#showme').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

**Check out** an updated version of your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/b0h6xd0t/4/).

**As an alternative**, as another answer has also correctly pointed, you can use:

```
$('#showme').fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).text(s).fadeIn(500);
});
```

**Putting `s` inside `text()` can also check its status**, because according to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-text) `s` is:

> The text to set as the content of each matched element. When Number or Boolean is supplied, it will be converted to a String representation.

In your case, as I pointed above, **the `empty string` is considered `false`**, so it fulfils the requirement.

**Note**: In this case, `$('#showme')` will fade out anyway, but if the value is `true` (not empty) it will fade back in. I'm not sure if you actually want that particular effect, so take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b0h6xd0t/6/) as well.

Comment: The first thing worked. I can't believe I missed the parentheses!

Comment: In coding it's always the little things :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the fade in as a function of the fade out, this allows the text to fade out, change, then fade back in. The if statements aren't really necessary. I also corrected the usage of `text()`.

```
$('#State').on('change', function() {
  var s = $('#State option:selected').text();

  $('#showme').fadeOut(300, function() {
   $(this).text(s).fadeIn(300);

  });

});
```

## [Fiddle update](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/b0h6xd0t/5/)

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
var s = $('#State option:selected').text();
```